# How to clip path in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image, styles

[image: img]

In css, to clip the image like abvoe, we can write:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 64%, 0% 100%);
```

But how to do the same thing in React Native?

I tried to use clipPath in `<Image>`, but the property does not exist.

Comment: your gonna have to use some underlays and tricks, or go the SVG way